# Print only once if something specific name is in the file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a problem. This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
file_name="eq3_luteina_horyzontalna"
file_name2="wiazanie_PO4"
tmp=$(mktemp) || exit 1  
for index in {1..405000} 
do
if ! [ -s "${file_name}_$index.ndx" ];then
    echo "0" >> ${file_name2}_POP42.txt
else
    awk '{if($2==/POP42/) print "5"; else print "0"}' ${file_name}_$index.ndx >> ${file_name2}_POP42.txt
fi
done
```

The problem is here

```
awk '{if($2==/POP42/) print "5"; else print "0"}' ${file_name}_$index.ndx
```

I want to only check if POP42 is in the file in the second column and print 5
but I have data like that

```
162 POP87
1851 POP42
```

so it will print into my output file ${file_name2}_POP42.txt, something like that:

```
0
5
```

but I want to have

```
5
```

Another situation

```
3075 POP42
2911 POP42
```

It will print to output

```
5
5
```

but I want only

```
5
```

How can I manage my problem?

Comment: Use `$2=="POP42"` or with a regex `$2~/^POP42$/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '$2=="POP42"{s=5; exit} END{print s+0}' file
```

By the way - `$2==/POP42/` doesn't do what you think it does, i.e. look for lines with `$2` equal to (or even containing) `POP42`. It's actually shorthand for `$2==($0 ~ /POP42/ ? 1 : 0)` courtesy of the regexp delimiters `/.../` you used and what THAT does is see if a string matching the regexp `POP42` occurs anywhere on the current line and, if it does, then test to see if `$2` has the value `1`, otherwise test to see if `$2` has the value `0`. It's important to know the difference between string (`"`) and regexp (`/`) delimiters and string (e.g. `==`) and regexp (e.g. `~`) comparison operators when using awk.